# How to update a column with the number of rows that have a matching column pair?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called related_clues which lists the id's of pairs of clues which are related

```
| id | clue_id | related_clue_id | relatedness | 
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+   
| 1  | 1       | 232             | 1           |
| 2  | 1       | 306             | 1           |
| 3  | 1       | 458             | 1           |
| 4  | 2       | 620             | 1           |
| 5  | 2       | 72              | 1           |
| 6  | 3       | 212             | 1           |
| 7  | 3       | 232             | 1           |
| 8  | 3       | 412             | 1           |
| 9  | 3       | 300             | 1           |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Eventually after a while we may reach two id's such as:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| id     | clue_id | related_clue_id | relatedness |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 121267 | 1636    | 38              | 1           |
| 121331 | 1636    | 38              | 1           |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

So in this case, for two distinct id values, we have the same (clue_id, related_clue_id) pair

In this case I would like the relatedness value to be updated to 2, signalling that there are two examples of this (clue_id, related_clue_id) pair. Like so:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| id     | clue_id | related_clue_id | relatedness |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 121267 | 1636    | 38              | 2           |
| 121331 | 1636    | 38              | 2           |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

So essentially I would like to run some SQL that sets the relatedness value to the number of times a (clue_id, related_clue_id) pair appears.

When I have no relatedness column present, and I simply run the SQL:

```
SELECT id, clue_id, related_clue_id, COUNT(*) AS relatedness 
FROM `related_clues` 
GROUP BY clue_id, related_clue_id
```

It gives me the required result, but of course this doesn't store the relatedness column, it simply shows the column if I run this select. So how do I permanently have this relatedness column?

Comment: Why would you want to store derived (and, presumably, dynamic data)?

Comment: The idea would be that this is continually updated

Comment: I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a update  with join

```
Update  related_clues  a
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT clue_id, related_clue_id, COUNT(*) AS relatedness 
  FROM `related_clues` 
  group by   clue_id, related_clue_id 
  having count(*) = 2 
) t on  t.clue_id = a.clue_id
          and t.related_clue_id = a.related_clue_id
  set a.relatedness =  t.relatedness
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as an update/join but filter out rows that don't need to be updated:

```
update related_clues rc join
       (select clue_id, related_clue_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        from `related_clues` 
        group by clue_id, related_clue_id 
       ) t
       on t.clue_id = rc.clue_id and
          t.related_clue_id = rc.related_clue_id
    set rc.relatedness = t.relatedness
    where rc.relatedness <> t.relatedness;
```